# Set Object to Object Without Pointer Javascript

Tags: javascript

In my program, I have 2 objects, A and B, with some code like this:

```js
var a = {"color":"blue"};
var b = a;
a.color = "orange";
console.log(b.color);
```

By setting B to A, they point to the same memory, and I don't want them to do that. I thought of running a for loop of all the keys and values, setting them individually to B, but there's got to be a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: ah, it also does. i just didn't know what deep cloning was, and i only need shallow cloning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to clone the object.

**But remember it is just a shallow copy**

```js
var a = {
  color: "blue"
};
var b = { ...a };

b.color = "red";

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(a.color);
console.log(b.color);
```

Comment: lifesaver! tysm! i'm just using json to store strings, so i don't think i'd need a deep copy

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries, like lodash, with clone functions, but for a simple, shallow cloning, you can use:

```
let b = Object.assign({}, a);
```